# JSON Parser displaying all content from server in same page Divide that to two pages

Tags: android

I am using JSON Parser to parse the response from server, i need only few pages to display in one Activity and some more in next Activity. In the code i am using it is displaying all content in one page only, when i click on that it is displaying the same content in Next Activity. How can i divide to make it appear in next Activity?

Comment: Get all content and show necessary content in Activity1, and in Activity2. What is the problem to separate data for the activities?

Comment: Only title,date and author name to display in Activity1, content contains description, some contents are more than 10 lines, so in Activity2 along with title,date,author name i need to display content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about this..

1) You can take a number of characters from the content string and display that in your list (and pass the whole string in the next activity).
2) Better yet, in the R.layout.list_item specify the number of lines the content textview should have (like android:lines=2 or something). The rest of the content will be cut. You can also use android:ellipsize to add an ellipsis where it gets cut off.

Answer (score 0):

1) use Intents to pass the server information  interns of strings

2) create a class to store the information , using get set to get the information in terms of strings